# How to change the interval of negative values? using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

My original interval is 100,  but i want to decrease the interval when there is a negative values.

Original
[image]

I want to achieve is:
[image]

Comment: thats cool. what code do you have for this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved my problem. 
So what i did was, I set the interval to 5 (you can set any number you want),
then I used the TickPosition property and i set it to [x, 0, 100] where 'x' variable is my least value.

ex.[-7.4, 0, 100]

And thats all!!!.

[image]